# openjdk-8-jre-headless : Breaks: ca-certificates-java (< 20160321~)

Tags: java, ubuntu, dockerfile, apt

Below command:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.0.1

ENV DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE 1

# This is FROM openjdk:8-jdk  
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        bzip2 \
        unzip \
        xz-utils \
                apt-transport-https \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-transport-https ca-certificates
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys AA8E81B4331F7F50

# RUN echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
RUN echo 'deb http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
RUN echo 'deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo debian-jessie main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list


RUN echo "Acquire::Check-Valid-Until \"false\";" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/100disablechecks

# Default to UTF-8 file.encoding
ENV LANG C.UTF-8

# add a simple script that can auto-detect the appropriate JAVA_HOME value
# based on whether the JDK or only the JRE is installed
RUN { \
        echo '#!/bin/sh'; \
        echo 'set -e'; \
        echo; \
        echo 'dirname "$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$(which javac || which java)")")"'; \
    } > /usr/local/bin/docker-java-home \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-java-home

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

# ENV JAVA_VERSION 8u111
# ENV JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION 8u111-b14-2~bpo8+1
ENV JAVA_VERSION 8u171
ENV JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION 8u171-b11-1~bpo8+1

# see https://bugs.debian.org/775775
# and https://github.com/docker-library/java/issues/19#issuecomment-70546872
ENV CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION 20140324

# RUN set -x \
#     && apt-get update \
#     && apt-get install -y \
#         openjdk-8-jdk="$JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION" \
#         ca-certificates-java="$CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION" \
#     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
#     && [ "$JAVA_HOME" = "$(docker-java-home)" ]

RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y  openjdk-8-jre-headless ca-certificates-java="$CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION" \ 
    && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre-headless \
            openjdk-8-jdk-headless \
            openjdk-8-jre \
            openjdk-8-jdk \ 
            # ca-certificates-java="$CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION" \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && [ "$JAVA_HOME" = "$(docker-java-home)" ]

# see CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION notes above
RUN /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure

##### END OF THE JDK

##### START Jenkins Slave Node Config settings

# Create Jenkins User
RUN useradd jenkins -m -s /bin/bash

RUN chown -R jenkins /home/jenkins
RUN chgrp -R jenkins /home/jenkins
RUN chown -R jenkins /tmp
RUN chgrp -R jenkins /tmp

# Add the jenkins user to sudoers
RUN echo "jenkins    ALL=(ALL)    ALL" >> etc/sudoers

# Must install docker to create docker images from docker container. Inception. Head... hurts.
# container must be called with -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    docker-engine \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# This must run after the docker install 
RUN gpasswd -a jenkins docker

USER jenkins
```

---

gives error:

```
Step 16/26 : RUN set -x     && apt-get update   && apt-get install -y  openjdk-8-jre-headless ca-certificates-java="$CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION"  && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre-headless            openjdk-8-jdk-headless          openjdk-8-jre           openjdk-8-jdk   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*  && [ "$JAVA_HOME" = "$(docker-java-home)" ]
 ---> Running in 3733400f9098
+ apt-get update
Get:1 https://apt.dockerproject.org debian-jessie InRelease [48.7 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.debian.org jessie-backports InRelease [166 kB]
Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [16.3 kB]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [44.9 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg [1652 B]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release [77.3 kB]
Get:7 https://apt.dockerproject.org debian-jessie/main amd64 Packages [7366 B]
Get:8 http://archive.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages [1171 kB]
Get:9 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages [20 B]
Get:10 http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9098 kB]
Get:11 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [892 kB]
Fetched 11.5 MB in 14s (818 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
+ apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre-headless ca-certificates-java=20140324
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openjdk-8-jre-headless : Breaks: ca-certificates-java (< 20160321~) but 20140324 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ERROR: Service 'slavedotnet' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c set -x    && apt-get update   && apt-get install -y  openjdk-8-jre-headless ca-certificates-java="$CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION"  && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre-headless            openjdk-8-jdk-headless          openjdk-8-jre           openjdk-8-jdk   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*  && [ "$JAVA_HOME" = "$(docker-java-home)" ]' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

---

How to resolve the certificate dependency?

Comment: please paste your entire dockerfile

Comment: @AnthonySottile Am unable to run the code at line #48, so trying to resolve it... with some alternatives.. Query edited.

Comment: why are you pinning `ca-certificates-java=...`? drop the `=...` part

Comment: @AnthonySottile `apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre-headless ca-certificates-java` gives error `openjdk-8-jre-headless : Breaks: ca-certificates-java (< 20160321~) but 20140324 is to be installed`

Comment: seems the openjdk backport for jessie (which is really old?  why are you still using jessie?) asks for too-new ca-certificates-java -- which is not backported.  I'd suggest using non-deprecated base images

Comment: @AnthonySottile Pleaase suggest your recommendations in answer. I will try follow that

Comment: I actually don't know enough about the aspnetcore images, but the dockerhub page suggests the one you're using is deprecated and to use these instead: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-aspnet/